# Question about the Z

Tags: statistics

I am confused while self-studying statistics.

It is about the standard score. I have no problem in understanding the formula $Z = \dfrac {X - \mu}{\sigma}$ and how it is used on area finding under a normal distribution curve.

Later on, when I come to Z-score test of a significant level, the formula Z becomes $Z = \dfrac {X - \mu}{\sigma} \times \sqrt n$. This probably is due to the central limit theorem, I guess.

My first question is “why the Z is treated differently?”

I also notice that some use $Z = \dfrac {X - \mu}{\sigma} \times \sqrt n$ but some use $\dfrac {X + 0.5 - \mu}{\sigma} \times \sqrt n$ (for the one-sided test). I understand that the +0.5 is the continuous correction for the discrete case.

My second question is “shouldn’t the answer for the same question be unique?” Or “the former is an acceptable answer while the latter will provide a more accurate estimate?”

Answer (score 1):

> Later on, when I come to Z-score test of a significant level, the
> formula Z becomes $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}$

This formula is incorrect. You find

$$Z=\frac{\overline{X}_n-\mu}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}$$

This because the sample mean $\overline{X}_n$ is approx (with CLT) Gaussian with mean=$\mu$ and variance=$\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$

For the second question yes, the result with the correction factor is more accurate when approximating a discrete distribution with a continuous one.

Note that you can have $\pm0.5$ as continuous correction factor; this depends on the situation you are dealing with

Comment: For the $\overline{X}_n$, is it because one sample is not good enough  for the estimation and we need more samples? What is the n referring to? The sameple size or the number of samples. Regarding the second question, is the answer (found by the former method) an acceptable one?